# Updating a object in mongoose results in loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my nodejs API app I have this route:

```
router.post('/startuserseries', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Geen username'});
  }

  User.findOne({ 'username': req.body.username}, function(err, foundUser){
    if(err)
      return next(err);

    if (foundUser) // check the value returned for undefined
    {
      foundUser.isdoingchallenges = true;
      foundUser.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error('ERROR!');
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

When I call this route in postman, the request never ends.
I have tried to use PUT but also didn't work, I tried various structures of code but neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This request will not finish because it doesn't write a response command on server.

You should solve easily this problem like below:

```
router.post('/startuserseries', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Geen username'});
  }

  User.findOne({ 'username': req.body.username}, function(err, foundUser){
    if(err)
      return next(err);

    if (foundUser) // check the value returned for undefined
    {
      foundUser.isdoingchallenges = true;
      foundUser.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
           res.json(err);
        }
      });
    }
    res.send(200);
    // or your specific result json object
    // res.json({"error":false,"message":"completed"})
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for such an answer, it saved me. send(status) is deprecated, now sendStatus(status) is recommended.